# std::list complains about missing 2nd template parameter (allocator)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, stl

I'm currently trying to compile a rather large project using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. I found that it compiles just fine with older versions but with this one I get errors whereever a `std::list` is used with just one template parameter.

```
error C2976: 'std::list' : too few template arguments
```

In every other project and when creating a new project, I can use `std::list` with the default allocator just fine so I'm guessing it probably has to do something with MSVC 2012 but I'm clueless what that may be.

Comment: Post the code where you get that error?

Comment: It would help if you posted a minimal test case that unexpectedly fails to compile with MSVC 2012.

Comment: Maybe some header not included? e.g. you have forward declaration of `std::list<T, A>`, and no definition?

Comment: Create a [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating the SSCCE was exactly the problem: it's a huge project and I couldn't reproduce the problem in a new project.

The problem became more apparent after defining `_VARIADIC_MAX=10` which turned the error message into `error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::list'` instead.

It turns out that there were includes for `map`, `set` and a few other headers which contained forward-declarations to `std::list`: adding the missing `#include <list>` in a few places fixed it!

I'm not sure why this compiles on other platforms and MSVC10 but probably the STL headers in these systems are structured differently.

Thanks also to @kassak for the hint, it certainly helped!

Comment: Don't write forward declarations of standard library types. The implementation is allowed to add template arguments with default values, so you run the risk of getting the declaration wrong.

Comment: Just had the exact same issue in VC2013.